# Jquery Ajax Data Post Problem in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery's AJAX in my project. Today, I used it somewhere else with all same themethods but it doesn't work.

Is there something wrong with my script?

#### HTML:

```
<a class='btn edit_receipe_btn' id='myreceipe-52'>Edit</a>
```

#### JQuery:

*(Click function works. When I put `alert(instance)` after `var instance` line, it works)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.edit_receipe_btn').click(function(){
   var instance = $(this).attr('id');
   var dataString = 'process=userReceipeEdit&instance='+instance;
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/ajaxs.php',
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
    });
});
});
```

#### PHP:

```
$prcs = $_POST['process'];
if($prcs=='userReceipeEdit'){
        $instance = $_POST['instance'];
        return $instance;
    }
```

It appears the problem is in the PHP. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do have `$prcs = $_POST['process'];` in your PHP as well, yes?

Comment: Yeah, I just added it to my post. It was there from the beginning in my code.

Comment: if you take out that if $prcs statement can you hit the page directly in a browser?

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` and show us what PHP is receiving.

Comment: @wajiw no you can't hit directly in a browser. But there are 3 other conditions which are using $prcs in my script. All other works with no problem. Just this one.

Comment: @dnagirl here is result, it looks OK: Array
(
    [process] => userReceipeEdit
    [instance] => myreceipe-52
)

Comment: Is that the entire PHP page? if so, you should echo instead of return

Comment: @Jasper oh my brain blowed at the end I think :) Yeah you are right. How can't I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please don't put 'solved' in the title. If something someone else wrote solved your problem, please upvote and accept their answer.

Comment: @George I wrote solved because Jasper didn't answered my question. The answer was in comments. I didn't want people to waste time on a solved topic. Should I still remove it? I answered myself but I cant accept it in 2 days.

Comment: You should move whatever solved it to an answer, and in two days time upvote it.

Comment: @jasper you should have written that as an answer.

Comment: I posted as an answer, for the sake of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that the entire PHP page? if so, you should echo instead of return

Answer (score 2):

As Jasper De Bruijn notified me, the problem was in my php script. I should use echo instead of return:
Wrong usage:

```
$prcs = $_POST['process'];
if($prcs=='userReceipeEdit'){
        $instance = $_POST['instance'];
        return $instance;
    }
```

Correct usage:

```
$prcs = $_POST['process'];
if($prcs=='userReceipeEdit'){
        $instance = $_POST['instance'];
        echo $instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things, output the error and check to make sure instance is not undefined.

Output the error like this:

```
$('.edit_receipe_btn').click(function(){
   var instance = $(this).attr('id');
   var dataString = 'process=userReceipeEdit&instance='+instance;
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/ajaxs.php',
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function(response, status, error)
    { 
        alert(response.responseText);
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have formed this POST like a get, not sure why.  Try doing this in JS:

```
var dataString = 
    {
        "process" : "userReceipeEdit",
        "instance" : instance
    };
```